# How can I change the index of array using angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I have this array in my typescript. I'm using angular 6.

```
formats: any = ['Years/Months/Days', 'Years/Months/Week', 'Months/Days', 'Week/Days', 'Week/Half Days', 'Week/4 Hours', 'Week/Hours', 'Days/Hours/30Min', 'Days/Hours/15Min'];
```

and this is my html code.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="format">
    <option [ngValue]="null">{{'Select Type' | translate}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let format of formats" [ngValue]="format">{{format}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the dropdown value with help of next and prevoius button.

Comment: drop down are supposed to changed by user not by using next and previous ... can you please further elaborate?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I also want to change the using button also. So users no need to open the dropdown. When anyone wants to see the full list then they will open the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to have a variable for storing the index of the selected option and initialize it to zero, every time the selected value gets changed update the index.

then you can create two buttons for next and previous with click event mapped to both buttons

the .ts file and function might look something like this

```
selectedindex:any = 0;

changed(event : Event):any{
 console.log(event)
if( event.target){
console.log( this.formats.indexOf(this.yourformobject.controls['format'].value))
this.selectedindex = this.formats.indexOf(this.yourformobject.controls['format'].value;
}
}
next():any{
 if(this.selectedindex < this.formats.length-1){
this.selectedindex++;
this.yourformobject.controls['format'].setValue(this.formats[this.selectedindex]);

 }
}

previous():any{
if(this.selectedindex>0){
this.selectedindex--;
this.yourformobject.controls['format'].setValue(this.formats[this.selectedindex]);

}
}
```

and the Html look like this

```
<form [formGroup]="yourformobject">
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="format" (click)="changed($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select Type</option>
    <option *ngFor="let format of formats" [ngValue]="format">{{format}}</option>
</select>
<button (click)="next()">next</button>
<button (click)="previous()">previous</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: The previous button working fine when you first click on the Next button. If you click on the previous button first then it is not working.

Comment: Yah this is because we are initializing the startindex to zero instead you can initialize the start index everytime to the selected item when you get the data from backend

Comment: You have to write some code when you get the data from backend to assign the startindex to the selected value

Comment: Yes, I made the changes to the previous button. I'm just telling you about this. If some will find this type of question and if he will find this, and the previous button Is not work. They will get confuse.